# How to copy a date from one row to another with matching (SCD Type 2)

Tags: sql, sql-update, scd

I've been struggling to write a query in SQL that sets the start_date of the company's new license plan to be equal to the expiration date/end_date plus one day of the company's previous license plan.

In the image below you can more clearly see what I'm trying to accomplish.

[Query description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqPZ2.jpg)

What I've tried so far:

Update dbo.license_case_study
Set start_date = [Expiration date]
where [Product service state] = 'active' and [Company ID] = [Company ID] and start_date is not null

The query above is obviously flawed, particularly where [Company ID] = [Company ID]. I was not sure how to copy the expiration date/end_date from the company's previous license plan to the company's new license plan. With [Company ID] = [Company ID] I was trying to match the two rows so that the end_date wouldn't be copied to some other company's new license plan.

The copying of the expiration date/end_date from companies' terminated license plans to companies' active license plans needs to be done for every company that has a new active license plan, not only for the one company in the image I attached to this question. Maybe I should use MERGE instead of UPDATE?

I'm greatly thankful for any attempts at addressing this question and am willing to provide more details if needed.

Best,

Axel

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. MERGE is probably the way to go

Comment: Thank you NickW